# Artinian rings, minimal ideals, and the Hom functor

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I was reading the Proof of Theorem 18.1 in Matsumura and there were two places where I was stuck.

> **Theorem 8.1** Let $(A, m, k)$ be an $n$-dimensional Noetherian local ring. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> (2) $\operatorname{Ext}^i_A (k,A) = 0$ for $i \not= n$ and $\cong k$ for $i=n$;
>
> (4') $A$ is a CM ring and $\operatorname{Ext}_A^n (k,A) \cong k$;
>
> (5) $A$ is a CM ring, and every parameter ideal of $A$ is irreducible;
>
> (5') $A$ is a CM ring and there exists an irreducible parameter ideal;

(4') $\implies$ (5) Let $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ be an $A$-sequence and set $B = A/\sum_1^n x_iA$. Then $A$ being Artinian implies that any minimal non-zero ideal of $B$ is isomorphic to $k$. Why is that?

(5') $\implies$ (2) Let $B$ be an Artinian ring with $(0)$ is irreducible. Then $\operatorname{Hom}_B(k,B) \not= 0$. I'm not sure why this is true...

Thanks in advance

Comment: For your first question, there is only one isoclass of simple module for a local ring. It has to be isomorphic to $A/m$. In particular, the minimal ideals must be isomorphic to that. This is true for any local ring, in fact, but Artinian rings are guaranteed to have minimal ideals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Actually $B$ is artinian, and a non-zero minimal ideal of $B$ is a simple $B$-module, so isomorphic to the residue field of $B$ which is $A/m$.
2. $\operatorname{Hom}_B(k,B)\ne0$ has nothing to do with $(0)$ irreducible. This is the socle of $B$, that is, $(0:_Bm)$, and since $B$ is artinian it is non-zero (why?).